# Laravel 5 update all Pivot entries

Tags: php, sql, laravel, pivot, laravel-query-builder

I have a Many-to-Many-Relationship between the User and the Customview Model:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * Customview relation
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function customviews ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Customview::class )->withPivot( 'default' );
    }
}
```

Now, I want to update **all the user's customview-assignments** and reset their default flag to 0.

By hand this should look like this in SQL (the pivot table's name is customview_user):

```
UPDATE `customview_user` SET `default`=0 WHERE `user_id`=<user_id>;
```

Is there a way to do this like this:

```
$user->customviews()->...update(['default' => 0]);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may have moved on from this, but for posterity I'll reply anyway as I found this question via Google.

It's hacky, but this does the trick:

```
$user->customviews()
    ->newPivotStatement()
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->update(array('default' => 0));
```

Comment: This is exactly how I did it then:
`$this->customviews()->newPivotStatement()->where( 'user_id', $this->id )->update( [ 'default' => 0 ] );`

Comment: What if I want to update some of the relations, not all? One way can be "including not updated relations also".

Answer (score -2):

Try with `updateExistingPivot` like this:

```
$user->customviews()->updateExistingPivot($customviewId, ['default' => 0]);
```

Comment: This works only with one row. I want to update all of the relations which are related to the user..